# Error in optional prop-types check in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I'm writing react typescript and have problem with **optional** prop-types check. Below is my code:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

interface InputNumberProps {
  className?: string | string[];
}  

export const InputNumberAutosize = (props: InputNumberProps, ref: refType) => {  
   ...
}

const InputNumberAutoSizeComponent = React.forwardRef(InputNumberAutosize);

InputNumberAutoSizeComponent.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)]),
};
```

Somehow my typescript throw error in className when declare like this.
Here is the error:

```
TS2322: Type 'Requireable<string | (string | null | undefined)[]>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<string | string[] | null | undefined>'.    
   
Types of property '[nominalTypeHack]' are incompatible. 

Type '{ type: string | (string | null | undefined)[] | null | undefined; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ type: string | string[] | null | undefined; } | undefined'.     

Type '{ type: string | (string | null | undefined)[] | null | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: string | string[] | null | undefined; }'.       

Types of property 'type' are incompatible.        

Type 'string | (string | null | undefined)[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | string[] | null | undefined'.          

Type '(string | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string | string[] | null | undefined'.               

Type '(string | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.   

Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.       

Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

This looks weird because as I read in the documents, the `prop-types` should be **optional** and accept `undefined`. Anyone know how to fix this, thanks.

**Update**: I think the problem come from **PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)**. The **arrayOf** cause the error.

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
        "types": ["node", "jest"],
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "strict": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/**"]
}
```

**Typescript version :** `"typescript": "^3.4.2"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set exactly the types of your optional values when they might be `undefined` or `null` in typescript. If you are in `strict` mode you have two options for this situation:

**1. Set the type for `undefined`s and `null`s**

```
interface InputNumberProps {
  className?: undefined | string | (string | undefined | null)[];
}
```

**2. Change your `tsconfig` to skip checking of `null` and `undefined` :**

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
        "types": ["node", "jest"],
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false, // this will skip that checking 
        "declaration": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/**"]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, is there any other ways that doesnt affect the `interface InputNumberProps`. Because I see the same code in different repo but there is no error from tslint. So I was wondering if there is any configuration related ( like you mention `strict` mode)

Comment: your welcome, please share your `tsconfig.json`, also the version of typescript that you are using?

Comment: You can find this helpful and check this with yours, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks

Comment: hi, i just share my tsconfig and version, can you help me check