# TypeScript optional properties not accepting undefined value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

```
<MyCustomField
    type={props.type}
```

MyCustomField's `type` type definition:

```
type?: string;
```

`props.type`'s type definition:

```
type?: string;
```

For some reason, I get this error:
[image: pic]

It feels like I accidentally turned on some setting. My tsconfig:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "esnext"
        ],
        "allowJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

**Edit:** In addition, it compiles fine:

[image]

It's just that VSCode Intellisense doesn't like it.

**Edit 2:**

```
if (!clone[index].options) throw Error(`Data at index ${index}, ${optionIndex} doesn\'t have options`);
if (type === FieldDataTypeEnum.RadioButton) {
    clone[index].options.forEach(o => o.checked = false);
} else {
    clone[index].options[optionIndex].checked = true;
}
```

This also gives me an error saying that clone[index].options is possibly undefined, even though the if statement should neglect that:

[image]

But still compiles fine.

Comment: The setting responsible is presumably `"strict": true`. I don't know much about React, but as a guess I'd say it's probably that React is interpreting `?:` to mean it's only allowed to be undefined if the attribute is absent.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a sandbox, https://www.codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: @AjeetShah No, like I said this seems to be an intellisense issue

Comment: In that case, you should just try to update your VSCode, close it and reopen it.

Comment: @AjeetShah I have.

Comment: It looks like your VSCode and your scripts use different typescript versions. You could select TS version in VSCode in the bottom right corner, while having a .TS file opened.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak that was it. Do post this as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, VSCode was using the newest beta version of Typescript, and not the version I had declared in the workspace.

This PR for their new beta version introduced some potential breaking changes, which is why you're seeing the errors you are.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43947

It introduces a new strict mode, --strictOptionalProperties. If you have `"strict": true` in your tsconfig, this new mode is enabled by default.

Someone made a suggestion here that will likely help make this more clear.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44403

To sum it up, you are seeing an Intellisense issue in VSCode because VSCode is using a new version of Typescript that introduced breaking changes. If you change your VSCode Typescript version to match your workspace, you should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment:

> It looks like your VSCode and your scripts use different typescript versions. You could select TS version in VSCode in the bottom right corner, while having a .TS file opened

Answer (score 0):

I think this looks very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64765671/12431728

Based on the linked answer, I think you have to specify `undefined` as a possible type for the prop, so `type?: string | undefined` for the prop type definition.

The other option they gave is disabling strict null checking in tsconfig.json by adding `"strictNullChecks": false` to `compilerOptions`.

Comment: That's weird, while I don't want to skip null checking, I also want to be able to pass optional variables to props that are optional. It's pretty weird how types of the same definition aren't compatible, this feels more like a bug.

Comment: IMO it makes sense. This isn't unique to React but rather TypeScript itself. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50491030/12431728

Comment: it compiles fine though, it seems like an intellisense bug to me, maybe a tsconfig setting?

Comment: It should compile fine, because whether the variable is assigned a value or is assigned `undefined` is not known at compile time.

Comment: similar issues do give me compiler errors, though